# When does the table collation will change?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Am created a new table in my_database DB. It has default database collation. but created table have some other collation as `Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. Can anyone please help me to sort out the problem as when does collation may change.

Comment: Tables do not have collations, columns do. Management Studio still confusingly presents collation as if it was a table property under "Extended Properties", but it is not -- this is just the database default collation. The only way to end up with columns that have a different collation from the database default is if the `CREATE TABLE` statement includes explicit `COLLATE` clauses. None of this should be confused with the *server* default collation, which is just the default used for new databases; changing server or database collation has no effect on the collations of existing columns.

Comment: But i didn't explicitly used collation anywhere even though columns are changed from default collation to `Latin1_General_CI_AS`

Comment: @Shahul, how did you create the table? If you run a `CREATE TABLE` script in a query window without explicit column collations specified, the database default collation will be used.

Comment: I'm going to say that's not possible on the face of it. Either your `CREATE TABLE` statement (however it's produced) includes `COLLATE` clauses, or the collation of your database is not what you think it is, or there's some DDL trigger on the server that's changing the statement before it's executed. There's also more basic possible problems like not being on the right server/database, of course. You can double-check the collations with `SELECT [name], collation_name FROM sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('MyTable')`